# White Noise after Rendered Scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, noise-reduction

When I render, white like bricks come up in my scene and start to affect the sand textures.

[image]

I've researched I thought it was a noise particle from using something transparent like water but the noise particles are more like circles than bricks.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project material and textures. Do you have overlapping planes for the white, brown and green parts?

Comment: Try increasing samples!

Comment: Over here, i think its the best if you add your scene, there are much things that can be it.

Comment: Hello, most likely you have an additional object sitting at the exact same place which you might had hidden in the viewport, but not deactivated for rendering